# Displaying Multiple Rows of Data from Two Tables with a One to Many Relationship

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, one-to-many

I have two tables. Tracks and metadata. Tracks can have multiple metadata attributes, but metadata can only be attached to a single track. The metadata table has a foreign key for a track ID, but the tracks table has no foreign keys for metadata. I am trying to find the best way to get this result:

```
[{
   trackID: 6,
   trackName: "test", /* these are the data from the tracks table */
   metadata: [
     {
        bpm: 123 /* This is the data from the metadata table */
     },
     ...
   ]
},
{
   trackID: 7,
   trackName: "test2",
   metadata: [
     {
        bpm: 135
     },
     ...
   ]
}]
```

Essentially, i am trying to get multiple tracks, with each track having multiple metadata attributes. The only way i've been able to think of doing this is to first query for the tracks

`SELECT * FROM tracks;`

then on the backend, for each track returned send another query

`SELECT * FROM metadata WHERE track=?`

What is the better way of doing this, without sending many many queries to the database?

I have also tried a JOIN such as:

`SELECT * FROM tracks LEFT JOIN metadata ON metadata.track = track.id WHERE track.id>5 LIMIT 10 ;`

but this would require parsing it on the backend and checking each row to see if it has an identical track ID and overall also seems sluggish and suboptimal.

Is there a better way of doing this, what is the best practice here? Thank you in advance.

PS: I am using Postgres, NodeJS and Prisma if that helps.

Comment: Sample data -- or at least the layout of the tables -- would really help.

Comment: I cannot address your exact requirements, much more info required,  but when addressing the "JOIN" option you say "require parsing it on the backend and checking each row". That is **exactly** what join does, you do not have to do anything extra, and it will be vastly faster then the 2 query option you have. It has loosely been said the purpose of a RDBMS is to do joins quickly. IMHO with the exception of complex display formatting, always do as much work on the back end as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use aggregation.  It is not clear exactly what your data looks like and what you want the results to look like.  For instance, if you only want the `bpm` column from `metadata` (as your results suggests), then this puts that value in an array column called `metadata`:

```
SELECT t.track_id, t.name,
       ARRAY_AGG(m.bpm) as metadata
FROM tracks t LEFT JOIN
     metadata m
     ON m.track = t.id
WHERE t.id > 5
GROUP BY t.track_id, t.name;
```

If you want additional columns, you can put the entire record in the array:

```
ARRAY_AGG(m) as metadata
```

And Postgres supports all of this with JSON functions as well.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, working flawlessly! Thank you so much!